# Не получается создать массив с 12 рандомными элементами?

Tags: javascript

Не получается создать массив с 12 рандомными элементами. Нужно найти сумму каждых соседних элементов, и делать в цикле for или while опять же массивы пока длина конечного массива не станет равна 1.
вот исходник 
не получается начать
Думаю задача ясна

```js
var array {
  12
};
array = Math.round(Math.random() * 100);
console.log(array);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Как то не понятно изложили суть вопроса. Вы с начало говорите создать массив с 12 элементами. А потом хотите что бы остался один. Можно конкретно по пунктам что именно требуется? И что у вас не получается ?

Comment: судя по всему это `var array { 12 };` "объявление" массива размером 12 элементов, а это `array = Math.round(Math.random() * 100);` его наполнение 12тью элементами, вам стоит почитать о массивах

Comment: 1) cоздать массив с рандомными елементами - 12 елементов

Comment: 2) посчитать сумму соседних елементов и опять вывести массив этих сумм

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> cоздать массив с рандомными елементами - 12 елементов

```js
var arr = [];
var newArr = [];
for(let i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
   let j = Math.ceil(Math.random()*100);
   arr.push(j);
 }
 console.log(arr);
 function sumPair(arr){
    while(arr.length>1) {
        for (let i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++)
                newArr[i] = arr[i] + arr[i + 1];
        console.log(newArr);
        arr = newArr.slice();
        newArr = [];
    }
}
sumPair(arr);
```

А вот второе если я правильно понял, сначала должно создать массив с 6 элементами,а дальше с 3?

Comment: да, верно, вот это и не могу сделать

Comment: Ну тогда скажите по какому принципу вы хотите сделать когда будет 3 элемента (первых два суммировать, а третий оставить, или как?), и я попробую помочь.

Comment: вот так например, только это нужно зациклить пока длина конечного массива не станет равна 1

Мой массив: 2,5,8,4
Сумма соседних элементов: 7,13,12

Comment: каждый раз массив будет уменьшаться только на один элемент?

Comment: получается да...

Comment: Исправил, пробуйте

Comment: Да, правильно. Я уже сам додумался вот так написал 

function sumPairs(arr) {
   var sum = [],
     i;
   for (i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
    sum.push(arr[i] + arr[i + 1]);
   }
   return sum;
  }

  var x = [2, 5, 8, 4];

  var l=x.length;
  document.write('My calc operation: '+l);

  document.write("<br>");
  document.write("My array: " + x);
  x = sumPairs(x);
  while (x.length > 0) {
   document.write("<br>");
   document.write("Array: " + x);
   x = sumPairs(x);
  }

Comment: а можно как то кинуть процесс создания суммы в отдельную функцию?

Comment: пробуйте, исправил